# Why is Convert.ToDecimal(3.1922) showing as 31922?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I'm reading a XML file with values in it. When I read them they are strings.

So when I try to convert them to `Double` or `Decimal` the point disappears.

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3.1922");             
MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString()); // 31922
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is related with your current culture

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3.1922",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString()); //31922

dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3.1922", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString()); //3.1922

dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3,1922", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString()); //3.1922
```

Comment: You should add the recommended solution too, namely explicitly specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: So what would be the best way? Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture or just create a Culture that 'works'. I.e. CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") works like I want it.

Comment: @Niels It depends on your specific case, but if you want to make your code work for many locales, use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: @L.B. Thanks for your answer. The values in the XML will always be in this format, and the GUI of my application will always be in English. So, what would be the best solution then?

Comment: @Niels I would use `InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 1):

In your current culture `.` is used as thousands separator. You can verify it this way:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var numberFormat = culture.NumberFormat;
string groupSeparator = numberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator; // will be .
string decimalSeparator = numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator; // will be ,
```

You can specify your desired culture for parsing:

```
decimal dec = Decimal.Parse("3.1922", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Or you can set your culture as current:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
decimal dec = Decimal.Parse("3.1922");
```

Comment: @Ons How do you know Niels's culture? For example the German culture uses `.` as thousands separator.

Comment: I am talking about general US culture. Culture is not specified here. And When I am running the code. it is showing fine.

Comment: *Culture is not specified here* so, why are you sure about current culture of OP environment?

Comment: @Ons Without specified culture the local culture is used. You cannot assume that this culture is the US culture. Use must `InvariantCulture` explicitly for this code to work reliably.

Comment: That is infact correct. So in this case prolly we can use culture invariant and it would work right ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.

Answer (score -2):

First add these codes in `public form1()` `after InitializeComponent();` :

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    }
```

Then use your codes wherever you want :

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3.1922");
        MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString());
```

Update :

If you don't want global change you should add the codes before showing decimal.

```
private void ShowDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal("3.1922");
        MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString());
    }
```

Update 2 :

```
decimal dec = Decimal.Parse("3.1922", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
MessageBox.Show(dec.ToString());
```

Comment: Global change for local problem => Bad design

Comment: @CodesInChaos He can change that before his codes. i just show him the way ;)

Comment: That makes it even worse. Since now clicking the button changes the state globally without restoring it.